# Java DecimalFormat, is it possible grouping in fraction part?

Tags: java, floating-point, decimalformat

I need to print small numbers (percents on histograms) but [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) do something strange. For:

```
System.out.println((new DecimalFormat("#,##0.######")).format(123456.000123));
System.out.println((new DecimalFormat("#,##0.######")).format(0.000123));
System.out.println((new DecimalFormat("#,##0.###x###x###x###")).format(0.001));
```

I got:

```
123,456.000123
0.000123
0.001xxx
```

Seems [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) designed for formatting currency only...

Is it possible to get grouping in fractional part with [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)?

Or suggest any other formatting library...

I expect such or similar:

```
GoodFormater("0.123456") === "0.123'456"
```

Comment: What output were you hoping for with the above lines?

Comment: Please if any downvote - describe a reason!!

Comment: `DecimalFormat` does not support separator for the fractional part.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I haven't seen any fractional numbers formatted like what you are saying, may be one reason for it not to be supported in the existing formatters. I'd also like to know why you want to format the decimal points (Just to satisfy my curiosity).

But I'd do something like this,

1.) Separate the whole amount and decimal amount. (123123.789789 into 123123 and 789789)

2.) Format them both separately. (123,123 and 789,789)

3.) Concatenate them with the `.` character and create the desired output (123,123.789,789).

It's some custom work, but personally I think it's better than writing something from scratch.

Comment: That won't work. The fractional part needs to be grouped from the right, the integer part from the left.

Comment: Data tables in scientific reports and the like often have grouping on the fractional part so you can read them better. e.g. `0.123 45`

Answer (score 0):

It seems perfectly clear from the Javadoc you cited that grouping only happens before the decimal point.

Comment: Can you suggest any other library for grouping in fractional part?