# How to format decimals separators in DecimalFormat

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting

I'm using DecimalFormat and need to add thousands separator to the decimal places of numbers. For example, I need to:

```java
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0##_#"); // ?
System.out.println(fmt.format(1234.0));     // 1,234.0
System.out.println(fmt.format(0.1201));     // 0.120_1
System.out.println(fmt.format(0.00001234)); // 0.000_012_34
```

How do I specify the format for the decimal places?

Comment: Duplicate of this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273849/java-decimalformat-is-it-possible-grouping-in-fraction-part

Comment: @MikeKim I think you are right. We're looking for the same goal. It seems that according to the answer, it's not possible to group after the decimal point. Sigh.

Comment: You just need to make a custom method that converts the fraction part into an integer, format that, and then append that formatted string to the original integer.